# Good, simple tool to split MP4 videos in Windows?

Tags: windows, mp4, splitter

I checked with "mp4 split windows" but SU didn't return much.

I'm looking for a simple Windows application to splice an MP4 video into 60mn bits. AviDemux is OK but it's a bit big and I had some issues with it. VirtualDub saves as AVI but I'd rather stick to MP4. mpeg2cut2 only handles MPG2.

Can you recommend something, preferable free?

Thank you.

---

Edit: For the benefit of others, I ended up using "[My MP4Box GUI](http://my-mp4box-gui.zymichost.com/)" (0.6.0.6).

Comment: Search for **Freemake video converter offline installer** and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Apparently, it can't be used to slice a video into multiple files, but rather it deletes parts of it: "Cut Video: Set the markers of the beginning and end of the part you want to remove"

Comment: Have you tried FFmpeg? `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -ss 0 -c copy -t 3600 out.mp4` – this would copy everything from 0 to 3600 seconds, for example.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do use ffmpeg when possible, but for some reason, the second slice has no sound when played in VLC, so I was looking for an alternative.